# Jquery how to fire function when mouse is x distance from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove

I would like to have a function run when the mouse is X distance away from an element.

I assume mousemove event should be moved, but since the element may not always be in the same place I'm not sure how to get the mouse position relative to the element?

Does anyone have an example of something similar?

Comment: with a sensitive boundingRect around or sensitive radius at corners?

Comment: @codelio I believe a sensitive radius at corners, but i'm not 100% sure I understand the difference.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the trigger function, with what to compare the mouse pos.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mX, mY, distance;
$element  = $('#YourElementID');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
        // do your stuff with distance

    });
```

Comment: Does this calculate from some point inside the element or from the edges or...? It seems like if I check for a distance > 100, I can go quite a ways out of the element from the bottom, but I cant exit the element at all before it fires if I try to leave from the top.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind to the `mousemove` event, store the coordinates of your elements corners in a global variable and keep checking at every pixel the mouse moved until the vector between current mouse position and your objects coordinates is of length X. that would then be the moment to trigger your custom event which you bound some function to.

i am unaware of a plugin that already does that, so make sure to post a link to the plugin you write here. :)